# Center image in table?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, centering

I have tried using vertical-align in CSS code, I have tried using align in inline CSS. But I just can't get the image to center properly. If only there were a horizontal-align property.

Here is the code as of right now. There isn't much in the code for either the HTML or the CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: violet
}
table.dog {
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}
table.cat {
  background-color: #FF91A4;
}
table.puppy {
  background-color: #CBA135;
}
table.kitten {
  background-color: #FF8243;
}
table.rodent {
  background-color: #6C2E1F;
}
table.lizard {
  background-color: #F8DE7E;
}
table.snake {
  background-color: #D70000;
}
table.turtle {
  background-color: #355E3B;
}
table.alligator {
  background-color: #171717;
}
table.crocodile {
  background-color: #556B2F;
}
table.bird {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
table.dog.female.goldenretriever {
  background-color: #0077BE;
}
table.dog.male.greatdane {
  background-color: #1C39BB;
}
table.dog.female.poodle {
  background-color: #007BBB;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Dogs</h1>
  <h2>Sophie</h2>
  <p></p>
  <table class="dog female goldenretriever" border="5" align="right">
    <thead>
      <th colspan="2">Sophie</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr colspan="2">
          <td class="dog.head">
            <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M241ab28f81f46d4c117cb21c6bd6d60co0&w=242&h=211&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0">
          </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Breed
        </td>
        <td>
          Golden Retriever
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Gender
        </td>
        <td>
          Female
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          No. of Puppies
        </td>
        <td>
          8
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Times pregnant</td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Health
        </td>
        <td>
          Healthy
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Age
        </td>
        <td>
          2 years
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

It is already vertically centered since the cell is the size of the image. But how do I get it horizontally centered so that it looks nicer? The colspan property doesn't seem to affect this image row at all.

Comment: `colspan` is an attribute on `<td>`s, not `<tr>`s.

Comment: How is that important for horizontally centering images? For a 2 column table it might automatically do it but what if I were to add more columns to a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here are some things that have I have done to your code:

1. First of all, there is some invalid syntax in your code- you opened `tbody` and then closed `thead`. Also as previously noted, I removed the invalid `colspan` that you were giving for the image `tr`. Another thing is that there is a dot in the classname `dog.head` which is tricky. First I fixed these issues.

   ```css
       body {
         background-color: violet
       }
       table.dog {
         background-color: SteelBlue;
       }
       table.cat {
         background-color: #FF91A4;
       }
       table.puppy {
         background-color: #CBA135;
       }
       table.kitten {
         background-color: #FF8243;
       }
       table.rodent {
         background-color: #6C2E1F;
       }
       table.lizard {
         background-color: #F8DE7E;
       }
       table.snake {
         background-color: #D70000;
       }
       table.turtle {
         background-color: #355E3B;
       }
       table.alligator {
         background-color: #171717;
       }
       table.crocodile {
         background-color: #556B2F;
       }
       table.bird {
         background-color: skyblue;
       }
       table.dog.female.goldenretriever {
         background-color: #0077BE;
       }
       table.dog.male.greatdane {
         background-color: #1C39BB;
       }
       table.dog.female.poodle {
         background-color: #007BBB;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <body>
         <h1>Dogs</h1>
         <h2>Sophie</h2>
         <p></p>
         <table class="dog female goldenretriever" border="5" align="right">
           <thead>
             <th colspan="2">Sophie</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td class="dog head">
                 <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M241ab28f81f46d4c117cb21c6bd6d60co0&w=242&h=211&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0">
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Breed
               </td>
               <td>
                 Golden Retriever
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Gender
               </td>
               <td>
                 Female
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 No. of Puppies
               </td>
               <td>
                 8
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>Times pregnant</td>
               <td>
                 1
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Health
               </td>
               <td>
                 Healthy
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Age
               </td>
               <td>
                 2 years
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </body>
   ```
2. So to center the image across table cells- you can't do that. That's why you have to use `colspan` on the `td` element- and that's all you need here.

   ```css
       body {
         background-color: violet
       }
       table.dog {
         background-color: SteelBlue;
       }
       table.cat {
         background-color: #FF91A4;
       }
       table.puppy {
         background-color: #CBA135;
       }
       table.kitten {
         background-color: #FF8243;
       }
       table.rodent {
         background-color: #6C2E1F;
       }
       table.lizard {
         background-color: #F8DE7E;
       }
       table.snake {
         background-color: #D70000;
       }
       table.turtle {
         background-color: #355E3B;
       }
       table.alligator {
         background-color: #171717;
       }
       table.crocodile {
         background-color: #556B2F;
       }
       table.bird {
         background-color: skyblue;
       }
       table.dog.female.goldenretriever {
         background-color: #0077BE;
       }
       table.dog.male.greatdane {
         background-color: #1C39BB;
       }
       table.dog.female.poodle {
         background-color: #007BBB;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <body>
         <h1>Dogs</h1>
         <h2>Sophie</h2>
         <p></p>
         <table class="dog female goldenretriever" border="5" align="right">
           <thead>
             <th colspan="2">Sophie</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="2" class="dog head">
                 <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M241ab28f81f46d4c117cb21c6bd6d60co0&w=242&h=211&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0">
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Breed
               </td>
               <td>
                 Golden Retriever
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Gender
               </td>
               <td>
                 Female
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 No. of Puppies
               </td>
               <td>
                 8
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>Times pregnant</td>
               <td>
                 1
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Health
               </td>
               <td>
                 Healthy
               </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 Age
               </td>
               <td>
                 2 years
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </body>
   ```
3. Still if need to know how to center in a `td`, see this example:

   a. Set a specific width for th `td` containing the image

   b. Use `margin: auto` strategy to center it.

   ```
   table.dog .dog.head {
     width: 400px;  
   }
   table.dog .dog.head img{
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
   }
   ```

```css
body {
  background-color: violet
}
table.dog {
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}
table.cat {
  background-color: #FF91A4;
}
table.puppy {
  background-color: #CBA135;
}
table.kitten {
  background-color: #FF8243;
}
table.rodent {
  background-color: #6C2E1F;
}
table.lizard {
  background-color: #F8DE7E;
}
table.snake {
  background-color: #D70000;
}
table.turtle {
  background-color: #355E3B;
}
table.alligator {
  background-color: #171717;
}
table.crocodile {
  background-color: #556B2F;
}
table.bird {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
table.dog.female.goldenretriever {
  background-color: #0077BE;
}
table.dog.male.greatdane {
  background-color: #1C39BB;
}
table.dog.female.poodle {
  background-color: #007BBB;
}
/* centering for illustration*/
table.dog .dog.head {
  width: 400px;  
}
table.dog .dog.head img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Dogs</h1>
  <h2>Sophie</h2>
  <p></p>
  <table class="dog female goldenretriever" border="5" align="right">
    <thead>
      <th colspan="2">Sophie</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="dog head">
          <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M241ab28f81f46d4c117cb21c6bd6d60co0&w=242&h=211&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Breed
        </td>
        <td>
          Golden Retriever
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Gender
        </td>
        <td>
          Female
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          No. of Puppies
        </td>
        <td>
          8
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Times pregnant</td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Health
        </td>
        <td>
          Healthy
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Age
        </td>
        <td>
          2 years
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

add colspan to td instead of tr

so remove colspan here :

```
<tr colspan = "2">
```

and add it here :

```
<td class = "dog.head" colspan = "2">
```

Comment: CSS class names cannot contain `.`, as far as I know. And even if they could, it would be a *really* bad idea to make use of it.

Comment: Yes,but the question was about something else and  I just copy his code to fix his problem which he mention!